# convert OpenGL RGBA byte array to android ARGB byte array

Tags: android, opengl-es

i can use the follow code to achieve convert OpenGL RGBA  int array to android ARGB int  array.

```
      int b[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
        int bt[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
        IntBuffer buffer=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
        buffer.position(0);
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h,GLES20.GL_RGBA,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
        {
            //remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
            //and so, some correction need.
            for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
            {
                int pix=b[i*w+j];
                int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
                int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
                int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
                bt[(h-i-1)*w+j]=pix1;
            }
        }
```

through i can use convert int array to byte array to  achieve my goal，but efficiency is little low，so i want to use the follow code to achieve the same goal:

```
final ByteBuffer rgbaData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4);
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgbaData),
```

Comment: @why is duplicate,your link only the color is change

Comment: I desktop OpenGL you can use `GL_BGRA` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` (see [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)), that converts from RGBA to ARGB. (Note ARGB is the reverse of  BGRA). Sadly this in not possible in OpenGL ES, even not in the most recent version 3.2